# Counting large amounts of data

Tags: php, mysql

My site has a social feature. On the user profile it shows how many posts the user has, how many followers and so on.

However our database has over 100,000 rows.

Its working fine however im getting very sceptical on the performance in the long run.

I was thinking of another method which i think would work best.

So basically right now it just counts the rows which the user owns in the mysql database.

Instead of scanning through the entire mysql table would it be better to do the following:

Create a section in the "Users" table called "post_counts". Every time he makes a post the counter will go up. Everytime the user removes his post it goes down and so forth.

Ive tried both methods however since the DB is still small its hard to tell if there is a performance increase

current method just querys SELECT * WHERE user = user_id  FROM table_name; then just count with php count($fetchedRows);

Is there a better way to handle this?

[update]

Basically the feature is like the twitter followers. Im sure Twitter doesnt count billions of rows to determine the users followers count.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: Hi, as ive mentioned the current method does not decrease performance at all right now. Ive implemented the other method and i cant see a performance increase.

Comment: Im interested in whether the new method will actually help when we have perhaps 1 million rows or more.

Comment: How can we tell you if a new method is better if we don't know how the old method is implemented?

Comment: Well what other explanation is required. It just users a MYSQL query to see which rows the users owns

Comment: SELECT * WHERE user = user_id  FROM table_name; then just count with php

Comment: Seems like you already answered your own question. Please don't treat these comments like a chat box

Comment: Yes i think i did, however im not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: You should put all relevant data into the question itself rather than comments so that others will see it and it can be properly formatted.

Comment: i vote for `post_count` in the users table. current method is crazy, why not `SELECT count(id) as COUNT FROM table_name WHERE user = user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have MySQL tables that have 70M+ rows in them.  100,000 is nothing.

But yes I would keep the counters in a field and simply update them whenever that users posts something or deletes a post.  Make sure you have good indexes.

Also what you COUNT() make a differences.  A COUNT(*) takes a less overhead than a COUNT(col) WHERE...

Use  "explain" to see how long different COUNT() statements take and how many rows they are scanning.

As in:  mysql> explain select count(*) from my_table where user_id = 72 \G;

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response

Comment: what is the "overhead" difference between `count(*)` and `count(named_col)` ?

Comment: That depends on what the column definition is.  If the value can be null or not will make a difference on a column count.